# Linear Second Order PDEs and usefulness of the canonical form.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I've been trying to solve a linear second order partial differential equation that looks relatively harmless $$ u_{xy}(1-x)(1-y)-u_x (1-x) -u_y (1-y) + u (1-d) -2w=0$$ 
whose domain is the unit square, $0<d<1$ and $w$ is a positive real with boundary condition $u(1,y)=\frac{2w}{1-d}$ for $y<1$ and condition $u(x,y)=\frac{w}{1-d}$ for $x=y<1$.

I am not an expert and all the notes I read guide you in transforming this PDE in a canonical form (I believe an hyperbolic form in this case). I thought there would be then a simple cookbook procedure to solve these canonical form, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Also obtaining the canonical form for the above is not immediate since the coefficients to the terms $u_{xx}$ and $u_{yy}$ (denoted $a$ and $c$ in what follows) are equal to zero so the usual formulas to get the equation for the characteristic curves $\frac{-b +- \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{a}$, are not useful.

Many thanks.

Comment: One of the issues with solving PDE is that seemingly harmless equations can even turn out to miss existence or uniqueness of solutions. So: 1) You said you have the canonical form, so please share it 2) Domain an boundary conditions of your problem are crucial when it comes to "finding" (in the sense of PDE) the solutions, so please specify them.

Comment: Hi - I hope it makes more sense now. I actually tried following the cookbook procedure to obtain the canonic form, though, as specified above, two out of the three coefficients are equal to zero. So I failed to retrive the equation for the characteristic curves...

Comment: I hope the headline improved. Grazie  @G.Sassatelli. If you know a good reference...